# Access local openfire from iphone jabber client

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am pretty much baffled with this please see if you can help out:

1) I have openfire installed on local machine
2) I created some user and added them to iChat jabber client "first@myMac.local"

can I configure a jabber client on my iphone as well which can use user "first" or basically establish a connection between openfire and iphone.

Thanks in advance
Ankit

Comment: You only need to make openfire client port (5222) visible on a public IP address

Comment: Also make sure DNS lookup of myMac.local works from your iPhone.